# How to get mobile signal strength in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Code attached below, but in iOS 13 app getting crashed. What can I do to fix this?

```
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    let statusBarView = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `statusBar` in this way was always a hack. Remove this code.

If your app really needs access to the signal strength, look at the NetworkExtension framework, and the NEHotspotHelper class.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help, and you have any sample code please,Im sitting 3 days for this.